# xrandr can't open display in running X session

Tags: xrandr

My external monitor is periodically flickering and I'm trying to debug it by reducing the refresh rate with `xrandr`.

However, when I run `xrandr` from within an active X session, the only output is "Can't open display"

```
[user@localhost ~]$ xrandr
Can't open display
```

I'm running gnome on Fedora 23 (and I'm not using wayland).

Comment: Do other X programs work (when executed from the same shell)? What is the output of `printf '[%s]\n' "$DISPLAY" "$XAUTHORITY"`? And `xdpyinfo | head -n 60`? Is this an “ordinary” local X session or something else?

Comment: `[][]` and `xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "".`, respectively.  Trying to open firefox from the command line also complains: `Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays`.  Let me try rebooting and verifying I'm in X.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting seems to have solved it.  I'm unsure what the original problem could have been.  Even with gnome+wayland, `xrandr` shows at least the current resolution.